# I am trying to use OpenStack horizon when i started server I got following error I tried to search but not getting anything ,can anyone help me?

Tags: cloud, virtualization, openstack, openstack-horizon

ImportError: Could not import settings 'openstack_dashboard.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named oslo.config

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it by re-installing python-paste, python-pastedeploy, python-setuptools.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using devstack then execute clean.sh and then do a stack again

```
cd /path/to/devstack
./clean.sh
./stack.sh
```

If you have installed it manually then you may have to install oslo.config using pip.

```
pip install oslo.config
```

Sometimes I have observed that not having execute permissions on the libraries also cause above error. Hope this helps.